# What's the etymology of "props"?

Tags: etymology

[Props](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/props) can mean compliment / respect / credit, for example:

> Erika gets props for the great work she did on the music.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/props) states that *props* is:

> (*slang*) *proper respect* or *proper recognition* for another person; an expression of approval or a special acknowledgment; accolade or accolades; praise.
>   
> - *I've got to give **props** to Roger for the way he handled that situation.*

How did this word come about? What is its etymology?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=props&searchmode=none):

> Props as slang shortening for proper respects (or something similar)
>   appeared c.1999.

There is an intermediate form *propers*, used in [Otis Redding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otis_Redding)'s *[Respect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respect_%28song%29)*, made popular by [Aretha Franklin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aretha_Franklin).

> give me my **propers** when ya get home

Answer (score 9):

*Props* is originally hip-hop slang, derived from *propers*, both similarly meaning *due respect*.

According to [The Rap Dictionary](http://www.rapdict.org/Props) ("the oldest and ultimate resource for looking up hip-hop slang"), *props* is:

> An abbreviation of "propers" or proper respects. A show sits on physical and non-physical props. At an award ceremony the winner gives props: "And I would like to thank...". "Cause this hip-hopper gets props just like a mobster" -- Da Youngstas featuring Pete Rock & C.L. Smooth (Who's the Mic Wrecka)

An older [Hip-Hop/Slang Dictionary](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/alt.rap/msD2c6Gz8jc) posted to alt.rap in June 1992 by Lee P Miller defines:

> props : 1) (n) Proper respects.

The oldest use I found in alt.rap is from [July 11, 1991](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/alt.rap/PYR4jyGYKH4) by Gregory Vincent Battle:

> Now wait a second here.  I have to give Hammer minor league props, even
>   before  "Hammer Don't Drown Em".  I personally HATED Hammer when I first
>   heard him.  He stole rhymes (worse than Shy D, that fuck), and
>   inimitable rap ideas ("yeahh boyeee"), and Too Big was more of a black
>   Pilsbury Dough Boy than a sidekick.  Shit, I'd kick him in the side :)
>   Well, I got free tickets to his first concert tour and I enjoyed it
>   completely.  His show was pure energy.  I think he might overdo it now
>   with his 60+ dancers/backup rappers/DJ's.  But hey, I still don't like
>   him enough to buy one of those wick-wack rekkids.

The *OED* also says it's a shorted plural form of *proper* with a first quotation from the *Chicago Tribune* (July 1990):

> I was one of the first female rappers, but I've always gotten my props.

The OED says *propers* is similar African-American slang for due respect, first quoted in the *Chicago Daily Defender* (January 1971):

> A level of existence which affords each black man his propers—dignity, pride,..and the ability to govern his destiny.

Answer (score -1):

I can see how it could be short for "give my proper respect"; but I think it's more basic than that; to prop is to support; if you offer your support for an action, you'd give them a prop; making it aplural makes it seem like you're gioving more?

Comment: Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Unsupported answers may be removed.

Answer (score -3):

being who I am [south american] I thought it originated with the latinos coming from 'propinas' - which is a tip or gratuity in recognition of good service/work - and, so as it is often used, giving someone their props would be giving someone recognition for something they've done.