# Simple word/ slang for "Re-share a content"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, vocabulary, phrase-requests, slang

I need a simple(commonly used/known) word or short slang(2 words max.) which means to re-share a piece of information with your network of friends. 
Something just like "***Share***" on social networks.

The word/slang is to be used in an application to let the user share a content with his friends. The content is not owned by him but just found by him & what he wants to also ***Re-Share*** with his network.

Something similar to ***Re-Share*** or like  ***Re-tweet***(as used by twitter) may be  a good fit. Could you suggest some simple word/slang to imply this ?

Comment: surely, i missed that important thing.. will do that now!

Comment: Perhaps *gossip*.

Comment: ***a** content*? You can (must) drop the indef. art. before *content*.

Comment: What’s wrong with **reshare**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a simple(commonly used/known) word or short slang(2 words max.) which means to re-share a piece of information with your network of friends. Something just like "Share" on social networks.

An example sentence , or several, of how you wish to use the phrase, would be useful.

Pass on  - "Material may be passed on"
 Pass along  - " ... passed along ..."
 Copy to   - REcopy is implicit.
 Share with   - sharing a shared resource is implicit.
Copy freely
Freely copiable - quite a common concept.
Public domain.
GPL licence.
Copying unrestricted.
Copying allowed.
Sharing permitted. / Resharing permitted.
Not copyrighted (see public domain).
 Share alike (as in one version of GPL licence)
Stallman rules   [ :-) ]

No restrictions on copying. (4 words)

Unlicenced ...
 Unrestricted.
 Fully free.

...

Comment: +1 `Pass on` & `Pass along` make better sense for my usecase.

Comment: Do you have some more suggestions similar to 
"Pass on" ?

Answer (score 1):

Would the phrase *Pay it forward* be too long? Or maybe it could be shortened to *Pay forward.* It is a concept that means, don't send "it" (whatever "it" happens to be) back to me or pay me back, just past it along to someone else. This [Wikipedia entry explains it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)

Or you could say *Fast forward*, playing off the old VCR term.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps “Send [Props](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/props)”, where *props* refers to  «”proper respect” or “proper recognition” for another person; an expression of approval or a special acknowledgment; accolade or accolades; praise».  For *props* etymology, see  [question #73636](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73636/whats-the-etymology-of-props) and see the randomhouse.com [20010213 WOTD](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20010213).   Or perhaps try *Do Tell*, a phrase that may ask for details or may express astonishment ([1](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090518201843AAjgSM7), [2](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/do-tell)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like "post on profile" or "post on wall" or whatever your users have. If not, you could invent a word for "post" (like *tweet* on Twitter or *blog* on blogs) and you could then have something like *re-tweet* or *re-blog*.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like *Copypasta*, it implies you didn't create it, you're just copying and pasting it somewhere else.

Comment: I presume you mean _copy-paste_, unless you have reason to believe that this question is specifically about Italian food?

Comment: Nope, Copypasta is a commonly used internet term for the copy-paste operation. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta

Comment: I see. I had somehow never seen that before. As far as I can make out, though, it refers to the actual text that has been copy-pasted, not to the act of copy-pasting it.

Comment: As with most internet terms, there is a gray area. I've seen it used both as a noun, and as a 'verb'. I'm of the mind it should be noun only though.

Answer (score 0):

Repost is a word I see a lot, but it's usually loaded with the negative connotation of recycled content that everyone has already seen. Reposting can be viewed as trying to reap the benefits of somebody else's work by using their content for likes, upvotes, karma, or whatever else the site posted-to uses.

Whether a repost is deemed positive or negative is usually based on the humility of the reposter and how blatantly they're just trying to use the content to farm points.