# Similar phrases meaning 'give kudos'

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

See, in one of our employee evaluation systems, we would like to implement a feature by which any employee can show appreciation to another employee that he has got help from or whom he thinks to be a good performer, mentor etc., and it has to be done every month. So, to give a name to this action, one of the suggestions was the phrase 'give kudos', but we would like to have a better phrase with a similar meaning. Something interesting!

Update: It is not mandatory that we should use the word 'give' or 'kudos' when we rephrase it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: *recognize*, *celebrate*, etc

Comment: Give brownie points.  (You could actually arrange to give the area a brownie treat in his honor.)

Comment: CenterStage, R&R- reward and recognition, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Praise**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/praise): say or write good things about (someone or something): *A good teacher praises students when they do well.*

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/praise_1): express strong approval or admiration for someone or something, especially in public: *Mayor Dixon praised the efforts of those involved in the rescue.*

Answer (score 1):

**[Recognition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recognition?s=t)** or **[acknowledgement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acknowledgment)** are common alternatives to **kudos** in the business environment.

Answer (score 0):

I like "brownie points" 
Something more informal: "Give a shout-out" or ["Give props"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73636/130012) 
You might consider including several, I think I've seen that elsewhere: "Give kudos, shout-out, brownie points, recognition..."  Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Thumbs-up** might be fun. They can give out thumbs-up "cards" for example, whenever an employee merits one; then add them up at the end of the month. (Much like grade-school teachers give those gold paper stars out to their pupils -or just use those same little stars!) Maybe there could be a small prize or other incentive at the end of the month to make it more interesting?

Answer (score -1):

You could play around the word *counsellor* or *adviser*, and their etymology.